# facebook app wont load in canvis php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

ok now I am getting quite hopeless I watched a few videos where people just put ulr in canvas and page would load inside of facebook.
here is a link to my github:

https://github.com/qazedx/facebook-php-sdk/tree/my_app

all I did was replaced secret app id and added h1 hedding but but when I try to enter my app it loads a blank page.
I have sandbox mode enabled and turned of secure browsing, what is preventing me from seeing my app content.

here is what I pasted in canvas:

http://test-test.eu5.org/my_app/

Comment: sandbox mode should be off, not on. else only admins can test it.

Comment: but I dont have a site that would have ssl, and I intend to try this app before publishing it

Comment: btw, safe browsing is irrelevant in that case, it´s only important for canvas and page apps. you are just using an external website and not a canvas or page app.

Comment: sandbox and ssl are different things. you do not need ssl, for external websites you NEVER need ssl in a facebook app, only for canvas or page apps. that is why there is no ssl input field for websites with facebook login in the dev settings.

Comment: so I entered in Site URL:http://test-test.eu5.org/my_app/index.php

Comment: turn the sandbox off and i can test it

Comment: btw, i see the content, no blank page. seems to work fine, i just cannot test the login with sandbox enabled.

Comment: did you take a look at the browser console? works perfectly fine, even the login.

Comment: ok, now that is weird, when i disabled sandbox mode it gives me an error that secure canvas is not supplied, I tried to load it on mozila and chrome both give me the same message, what am I doing wrong

Comment: where exactly do you test it? did you add the app to a page? or do you really just open the link you posted?

Comment: https://apps.facebook.com/576269352410010/?fb_source=myapps

Comment: of course you need ssl for that, even for testing :/ - oh well, i will add an answer then. please add EVERY detail in the question next time, that one was important ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app works fine on the external link/website, and you don´t need SSL for external apps. Since you want to create a Canvas App that is embedded in Facebook (apps.facebook.com/namespace) you need SSL or it will not work. Heroku offers free (shared) SSL for that: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

Sandbox mode is only for enabling/disabling an app for guests, activated Sandbox mode means that only Admins of the App can access/use it. In this case it´s irrelevant because only you need to see it right now.